# How to set log file for the mongod instance that runs during database initialization?

Tags: mongodb, docker

When running the `mongo` docker container, you can initialize your database by adding a script to the container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory. The [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) for this feature are under 'Initializing a fresh instance'.

If you do this, the mongo server `mongod` runs two times. The init scripts are executed against a first, *temporary* `mongod` instance. Once this instance shuts down, a second, *real* instance is started and runs forever.

The problem is that any config file applies only to the *real* instance and not the temporary one.

The docs specify only three env variables to configure the first instance:

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
```

None of these has anything to do with logging. I checked the [source code](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/4.4/docker-entrypoint.sh) of the docker image and unfortunately, there don't seem to be any other undocumented env variables.

I was thinking about setting the log file at runtime using `mongosh`, but this does not seem possible. The closest thing you can do is to [set the verbosity](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a config file with required logging settings https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemlog-options. e.g.

```
systemLog:
   verbosity: 5
   path: /tmp/mongodb_init.log
```

Map it as `/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-config.json`, e.g.

```
docker run -d -v /path/to/the/file.conf:/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-config.json mongo
```